# Special Shabbos pajamas

Tags: shabbat, sleep

I heard in a shuir that the Kaf H'chaim writes that one should have special shabbos pajamas. Does anyone know where it says it

Comment: In 262:24 he states that a person should not wear anything he wears during the week.

Comment: @Avrah He says not to wear any מלבוש he wore during the week. It's questionable if that would include pajamas.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the Kaf HaChaim quoted here:

https://tablet.otzar.org/#/b/641854/p/-1/t/1/fs/gTRuwpUE3IeaCIu45ZtvoWQGtJthRaci9TcqIVCXhZEQ/start/142/end/144/c

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The link for me doesn't open a sefer.

Comment: @Avrah It took a minute to load for me. It's a footnote referencing another sefer. You can see a screenshot in my pending [edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/48800).

Comment: Can you please include an exact reference to the kad hachayim itself?

Comment: Please enter the English as well

Comment: Please enter the English as well